# How to correctly use a backreference within a replacement string in gsub?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am a little confused about the behaviour of gsub in R, which I am using to rename variables in a `data.table`.  I would like any variable ending in `.y` to be renamed to start with a `c_` instead.  However, I get the following output:

```
> gsub('[.]*\\.y', 'c_\\1', c('v1.y', 'v1'))
[1] "v1c_" "v1"
```

When I would've expected:

```
> gsub('[.]*\\.y', 'c_\\1', c('v1.y', 'v1'))
[1] "c_v1" "v1"
```

I've seen many questions on SO about gsub and backreferences, however, none appears to explain this surprising (to me) behaviour. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use backreference you need to have a capture group. Try this -

```
sub('(.*)\\.y$', 'c_\\1', c('v1.y', 'v1'))
#[1] "c_v1" "v1"
```

The capture group `(.*)` captures everything before `".y"` and appends it to `"c_"`. For strings not ending with `".y"`, the output is not changed.

Comment: Why does `gsub('([.]*)\\.y', 'c_\\1', c('v1.y', 'v1'))` not work?  Is there a difference between `([.]*)` and `(.*)`?

Comment: @s.willis `[.]` means exactly a dot (same as `\.`), but `.` means any symbol.